# winboot.exe Signature Error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 that sits in a corner providing DHCP and DNS to an isolated network.  I've treated it with neglect; please don't flog me!

Every now and then Microsoft provides a security update.  This Crash Tuesday they made it so secure it won't boot at all.  The error is that the signature on Windows\System32\winboot.exe cannot be verified.  I've tried the following:

- Replace winboot with a copy from a working Windows 10 system; same error.
- Replace winboot.exe with a copy from a backup.  Turns out the digital signature on the backup is expired.
- Boot with driver checking turned off; STOP error.
- Following Justin Grimes' suggestion, I tried `bootrec /fixboot` which succeeded and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` which failed because it could not find a Windows installation in the disk.
- Tried `sfc /scannow` and got "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service."

I did the replacements by removing the disk and connecting it to a Win10 system; I had to take ownership of the directory and file to do that.

Other than flogging *myself* for not keeping up to date and using a Raspberry Pi for DHCP and DNS, what can I do?  I'd really like to get this box to boot at least once more so I can read some settings.  Thanks!

---

**Resolution:** I am going to give up and do what I should have done two days ago.  I've recovered the data by attaching the drive to another computer.  I'll have a hard look at how this machine is used and install either Server 2019 or Windows 10.  I really did put DNS and DHCP on a Raspberry Pi as an emergency measure right after the failure, and I'm going to leave that as is.  There's much less to go wrong with the Pi. I have a backup of the microSD card; I can replace the SD or the entire machine in a few minutes if need be.

Comment: If you can get to a recovery command line you can try bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /rebuildbcd. Perhaps backup the boot record first.

Comment: @JustinGrimes  Thank you.  I can get to a command line and I tried that, but that doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try sfc /scannow to be sure the disk is not corrupted and if that does not work perhaps try this... https://www.thewindowsclub.com/digital-signature-for-this-file-couldnt-be-verified-0xc0000428

Comment: @JustinGrimes  I'll give it a try in the morning.  Thank you for staying with me.

Comment: @JustinGrimes Well, sfc /scannow didn't work, and I've really run out of time to deal with this.  I really appreciate the effort you made to help me.  Thanks.  (If you post "give up" as an answer, I'll accept it to keep this from popping up time after time.)

Comment: Haha, no worries man. Sorry you couldn't get it working in time. I run a Pi for DNS/DHCP with PiHole at home. It gets the job done. At work I'm strongly considering Esxi virtualization for the new year for this kind of stuff. I highly recommend you to look into it as well.  Good luck!